# Rails 4 Nested Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have three models:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :item_points
   has_many :groups,  through: :item_points
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_points
end

class ItemPoint < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :item
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :group
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_points
  has_many :items, through: :item_points
end
```

The schema for `items`

```
create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name",       null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

The schema for `item_points`

```
create_table "item_points", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.decimal  "points",          null: false
  t.integer  "item_id",         null: false
  t.integer  "group_id",   null: false
  t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
end
```

The schema for `groups`

```
create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",       null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

In my `groups` table, I've created a number of rows, e.g. **group 1** and **group 2**.

In the form for creating `items` I'd really like to see a field each for `group 1` and `group 2`, so that I might be able to enter the points for that item.  e.g. In item X, group 1 is worth 10 points, and group 2 is worth 5 points.

**EDIT  Added the form**

The form:

```
 <%= form_for(@item) do |item_form| %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= item_form.label :name %>
        <%= item_form.text_field :name, :class => 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <%= item_form.fields_for(:groups) do |groups_form| %>
        <% group = groups_form.object_id.to_s%>
        <%= groups_form.hidden_field :id %>
        <%= groups_form.fields_for(:item_point) do |entity_form| %>
          <%= entity_form.text_field :points %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

This provides me with a form, which contains one extra entry box, called `item[groups][item_point][points]`, and has no label.

What I'd like to know is how do I get **all** of the rows I've added into groups as fields into a Rails Form? And when I do, how do I save the associated item_points data using strong parameters?

I've spent quite some time looking for an answer, and I can't seem to find anything other than a series of StackOverflow questions, which don't quite seem to have the same problem as me.

All help is wonderfully appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer, but just wanted to point out that you either need to change group_id to item_group_id in the item_points table or add `foreign_key: group_id` to the `belongs_to :item_group`

Comment: Thanks. That's a typo on my part :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a helpful post with some examples at: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through. It specifically talks about adding `inverse_of` on your associations.

In your view you'll need to use [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for). You could (for example) put that in a table or a list and have each entry be a row.

If you share what you've tried in your view so far you may be able to get a more detailed response if you need it.

As for `permitted_params` in your controller, you can nest them something like:

```
def permitted_params
  params.permit(item: [
    :name,
    item_points_attributes: [
      :id,
      :points,
      :group_id,
    ]
  )
end
```

**Update:**

Rather than `fields_for(:groups)` I think you want your controller to build the models for all the item_points (`@item_points = Group.all.collect {|group| ItemPoint.new({group_id: group.id, item_id: @item.id}`). 
Then you can use a `fields_for(:item_points, @item_points)`.

You can add a label for the field so it's not just an unlabeled field using the HTML label tag.

Comment: I've added part of the offending form. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Rather than `fields_for(:groups) I think you want your controller to build the models for all the item_points (`@item_points = Groups.collect {|group| ItemPoint.new({group_id: group.id, item_id: @item.id}`). Then you can use a `fields_for(:item_points, @item_points)`. You can add a label for the field so it's not just an unlabeled field using the HTML label tag.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't apply `collect` onto the ActiveRecord model. It needs to be applied to a scope iirc.

Comment: That's better :)  but  I still have a problem with the following code in the view just isn't working at all:  `<%= fields_for(:item_points, @item_points) do |points_form| %>
            <%= points_form.label :points, "#{@item_points.group.name}" %>
          <% end %>`

Comment: Oh, silly me!  It's working, wonderfully well. I've changed the view: `<%= item_form.fields_for(:item_points, @item_points) do |points_form| %>
            <%= points_form.label :points, "#{points_form.object.group.name }"%>
            <%= points_form.text_field :points %>
            <%= points_form.hidden_field :group_id %>
          <% end %>`

Comment: I'd mark your comment as an answer if I could. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I've updated my answer with the info that I think you found useful. Hopefully that makes the answer good. :)